# posible sums without reps up to given number

Tags: python, list, sum, combinations

I have task where I need to calculate all possible sums up to given number. For example:

```
mass_list = [4, 1, 8]
```

and max sum value is 10 `mass = 10`

Output need to be like this `>>>[1, 4, 5, 8, 9]` 5(1+4) and 9(8 + 1)

So far I came up with this

```
quantity, mass = map(int,input().split())
mass_list = []
for x in range(1, 2):
    mass_list.extend(input().split(' '))
mass_list = list(map(int, mass_list))
count = len(mass_list)
```

Would appreciate any help with solution

Comment: What are you currently getting, how is not working?

Comment: Part of answer will be lists elements, but I don`t know how to find their combination.

Comment: Perhaps look into [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=combinations#itertools.combinations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from itertools import combinations

max_val = 10
results = []
for i in range(1, len(mass_list)):
    results.extend(
        [sum(c) for c in combinations(mass_list, i) if sum(c) < max_val]
    )

results
[4, 1, 8, 5, 9]
```

(Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702120/2799941))

Comment: Just start from `1` in the `range()` and you can avoid the extra `sum(c) > 0` condition.

Answer (score 0):

use `itertools`:

```
import itertools

mass_list = [4, 1, 8]
mass = 10
output = []

for i in range(1, len(mass_list)):  # for each possible combination length
    for subset in itertools.combinations(mass_list, i):
       sum = 0
       for subset_element in subset:  # calculate sum of combination
          sum += subset_element
       if sum <= mass:  # do the check
          output.append(sum)

output.sort()
print(output)
```

prints:

```
[1, 4, 5, 8, 9]
```